# Include the minus superscript in a JButton's text

Tags: java, html, swing, jbutton, superscript

I am trying to set the text of my JButton to "Compute b⁻¹ (mod a)" in UTF-8 encoding, but neither of these two attempts work.  The problem is the minus superscript, but not sure what I can do.

Attempt 1:

```
_computeModInverseButton = new JButton("Compute b⁻¹ (mod a)");
```

[image]

Attempt 2:

```
    _computeModInverseButton = new JButton("Compute b<html><sup>-1</sup></html> (mod a)");
```

[image]

So the problem was my HTML formatting, but now with

```
_computeModInverseButton = new JButton("Compute b-1 (mod a)");
```

It looks like[image]

How can I format this to fit well with the superscript?

Comment: What if you html the whole thing? `new JButton("<html>Compute b<sup>-1</sup> (mod a)</html>")`

Answer (score 5):

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

> To specify that a component's text has HTML formatting, just put the
>    tag at the **beginning of the text**, then use any valid HTML in
>   the remainder. Here is an example of using HTML in a button's text:

```
button = new JButton("<html><b><u>T</u>wo</b><br>lines</html>");
```

Comment: I updated my question asking how I can format the button's text properly including the html superscript, do you know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, you should wrap the whole String in HTML:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("<html>Compute b<sup>-1</sup> (mod a)</html>");
```

Comment: I updated my question asking how I can format the button's text properly including the html superscript, do you know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: all text needed to be in the html tags.

_computeModInverseButton = new JButton("Compute b<sup>-1</sup> (mod a)");